# Why won't my applet appear in a web browser

Tags: java, miglayout

I have recently begun using MigLayout and with some trouble I manged to learn how to get it into a project.  I have added it to the project and the classpath but now MigLayout will not appear in any web browser.  other applet run just fine, but the one using MigLayout does not.  what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What 'project'?  What 'classpath'?  The only paths of relevance to an applet in a web browser are the `codebase` attribute combined with the archives listed in the `archive` attribute.  (Unless loose class files are being used, in which case, don't do that.)  BTW - open the Java console, copy/paste the errors.

Comment: no errors to post or I would have.  Sorry but it only seems to be a problem when I run it in a web browser

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the Jar containing MigLayout is added to the `archive` attribute of the `applet` element.

Comment: Sorry I'm rather new at this.  I have to put it into a jar?  (I know how to do that part)  beyond that I'm not sure what you said.

Comment: Actually your comment really helped!  I looked up what your were talking about ti got ti to work!!!  Thank you very much!!

Comment: @Brent:  Glad you got it sorted.  :-)  If my answer helped in that process, please mark it correct so it is easier to find later.